Confusing Goldstein Statement about Magnitude of the Lagrangian
On page 345 of Goldstein's Classical Mechanics 3rd Ed., he writes:

...the Hamiltonian is dependent both in magnitude and in functional form upon the initial choice of generalized coordinates. For the Lagrangian, we have a specific prescription, $L=T-V$, and a change of generalized coordinates within that prescription may change the functional appearance of $L$ but cannot alter its magnitude.

This statement seems to imply that the Lagrangian is a conserved quantity, which I know is not just incorrect, but wildly incorrect. What is Goldstein trying to say here?

Briefly speaking, Goldstein is trying to convey that the Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q},t)$ is invariant under passive change of generalized coordinates, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post; while the Hamiltonian is not always invariant, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.

I should note that my above quote from Goldstein is in the same paragraph in which the conservation of H in time is discussed. So if what he is trying to convey is what you say it is, it is perhaps an editing mistake of where Goldstein chose to put this comment!

Note also that your links are primarily about the invariance of the Lagrange or Hamilton's equations under coordinate transformations, not the L or H itself.
